# Before and After Action Conditionals in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Say I wanted to perform a conditional action; to

1. check if a glibc library is updated, if so, skip the below steps
2. stop mongodb
3. update glibc
4. restart linux

So far I can do the following:

```
- name: install updated glibc
  yum: name=glibc-2.12-1.166.el6_8.0.x86_64 state=present
  sudo: yes
  notify:
    - stop mongodb
    - restart vm
```

I have handlers to perform the subsequent actions, but I want to stop mongodb before I update glibc. As you can see, I am not able to perform the desired order.

I was looking through the ansible documentation and the stack overflow boards, but I could not find what I was looking for on how to accomplish this. Is this able to be accomplished in ansible? Should ansible be used for single updates such as these?

Thank you!

Comment: This was the first result of a Google search: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Ansible_-_Only-do-something-if-another-action-changed.html. I have not tested it myself yet, but it sounds like what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. I must have searched for the wrong terms.

Comment: I searched for "Ansible notify if changed". BTW, if this is the correct solution, and after you've tested it, you may want to answer your own question (for the sake of others SO users who may have the same need).

Comment: Yes, good idea, I am going to test this in a project and post my results here.

Comment: I would like to add that I tested the solution you proposed, and I verified that it does work. However, there is a problem with the yum module in the solution.  This module performs an install if the state is changed; I want to check the version, stop mongodb, and perform the installation after stopping the mongodb service. I will have to look for how to obtain that information and store it in the register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option here is to previously compare the versions. So you need to manually check which version is installed and which version should be installed and if it differs, do your things. Here's an example of how I did this once for git, quickly re-written for glibc. It might need some more work on it but should give an idea how to do it.

```
---

- name: Detect latest available glibc version
  shell: "`which yum` info glibc | grep Version | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev"
  changed_when: false
  register: glibc_install_latest_version

- name: Detect currenty installed glibc version
  shell: "ldd --version | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f4"
  changed_when: false
  register: glibc_install_current_version

- name: Stop mongo!
  ...
  when: glibc_install_latest_version.stdout != glibc_install_current_version.stdout

- name: "Install latest version of glibc"
  yum:
    name: glibc
    state: latest
    update_cache: yes
  become: yes
  when: glibc_install_latest_version.stdout != glibc_install_current_version.stdout

...
```

The reboot still can be triggered by your handler.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for! It is unfortunate that ansible does not support version checking in the yum module.

Comment: I would like to add that the "state=xxx" property is not required. Thus, the yum package module can be used to check if a package is installed. This solves my problem.